# Angular js remove table row not working

Tags: angularjs, html-table

When I remove table row in Angular it's removing all rows after index, I want to remove the particlar row.

**HTML :**

```
<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Date of GPA</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Grade</td>
        <td>Standard GPA</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="gpa in ctrl.gpatests">
        <td>
            <md-input-container>
                <input ng-model="gpa[$index].date" ui-mask="99/99/9999">
            </md-input-container>
        </td>
        <td>
            <md-select ng-model="gpa[$index].type" ng-required="true">
                <md-option ng-value="item.id" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.dispHsGradYr">{{item.displayName}}</md-option>
            </md-select> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <md-select ng-model="gpa[$index].grade" ng-required="true" >
                <md-option ng-value="item.id" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.dispHsGradYr">{{item.displayName}}</md-option>
            </md-select> 
        </td>
        <td>3.0</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="gpa[$index].id"/>{{$index}}<span ng-click="removeGPAScore(gpa[$index].id)"> x </span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="md-raised md-primary savebtn md-button md-default-theme" ng-click="addGPAScore()" type="BUTTON" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ng-scope">ADD GPA</span>
</button>
{{ctrl.gpatests | json}}
</div>
```

removeGPAScore , addGPAScore functions

**Script :**

```
$scope.addGPAScore(){
    var data = {};
    data.id ='' ;
    data.date ='' ;
    data.type ='';
    data.grade ='';
    data.gpaValue ='';
    ctrl.gpatests.push(data);
}

$scope.removeGPAScore(index){
    ctrl.gpatests=newDataList;
    ctrl.gpatests.splice( index, 1 );
}
```

What went wrong in the script.?

Comment: You mean you want to remove dom element or remove data associated with that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are `splice`-ing on the same array, you need to pass `$index` itself instead of `gpa[$index].id` to the `removeGPAScore` function. Like this,

```
<span ng-click="removeGPAScore($index)"> x </span>
```

Comment: When I Delete it its still removes the other rows. can you please create a JS fiddle for me.

Comment: Can you add more Script to this plnkr please

Comment: it's still removing all the rows after that particular id. I think my add more script has some issue.

Comment: Yes, i Found Issue in Add Script. i have give wrong model name

Comment: @Developer glad you found it.. hope it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Why is that `ng-click="removeGPAScore(gpa[$index].id)">` ?

Mention it as: `ng-click="removeGPAScore(gpa[$index])">`

Comment: is my add row script is correct .? can you optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ng-model="gpa[$index].date"` with Use `ng-model="gpa.date"`

Then Use

```
 $scope.removeGPAScore(index){
    ctrl.gpatests=newDataList;
    ctrl.gpatests.splice( index, 1 );
}
```